tengo un problema con el sharp en un archivo node
me sale el error luego de hacer
npm install
npm run build
npm run start
intente reinstalar node, bajar otra version, limpiar el cache de npm, bajar herramientas de compilacion, reconstruir sharp, o instalar dependencias de sharp, pero nada funciona y no se que mas hacer, si a alguien le paso algo parecido le agradeceria muchisimo que me diga
C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Escritorio\pasantias\pasantias\tiwi-cine-ts\node_modules\sharp\lib\sharp.js:114
throw new Error(help.join('\n'));
^

Error: Could not load the "sharp" module using the win32-x64 runtime
ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED: The specified procedure could not be found.
\?\C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Escritorio\pasantias\pasantias\tiwi-cine-ts\node_modules@img\sharp-win32-x64\lib\sharp-win32-x64.node
Possible solutions:

Ensure optional dependencies can be installed:
npm install --include=optional sharp
yarn add sharp --ignore-engines
Ensure your package manager supports multi-platform installation:
See https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#cross-platform
Add platform-specific dependencies:
npm install --os=win32 --cpu=x64 sharp
Using the canvas package on Windows?
See https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#canvas-and-windows
Check for outdated versions of sharp in the dependency tree:
npm ls sharp
Consult the installation documentation:
See https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install
at Object. (C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Escritorio\pasantias\pasantias\tiwi-cine-ts\node_modules\sharp\lib\sharp.js:114:9)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Escritorio\pasantias\pasantias\tiwi-cine-ts\node_modules\sharp\lib\constructor.js:10:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:10)
Node.js v20.4.0


Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.
